# Free sex change meaning

Tags: word-choice

What is the meaning of "free sex change" in this context?

"The city of San Francisco has decided to provide free sex change operations for employees who have worked for the city for at least one year."

I provided the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The **sex** of a person or animal is their characteristic of being either male or female.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sex)

**sex change** refers to the procedure of changing it (known as [sex reassignment surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_reassignment_surgery)).

**free sex change** means it's offered free of charge.